# How do I add a value to a click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to add an attribute/value to each click of similar elements to use that value somewhere else. The code I'd like to use it is something like

```
<div class="productbox"><img src="image.png"></div>
<div class="productbox"><img src="image2.png"></div>
<div class="productbox"><img src="image3.png"></div>

<div class="differentcontainer">
<!-- the value of the image shall be put in here as <img src="..."> -->
</div>

$(".productbox").click(function() {
    var imgname = $(this).next(img).value;
$(".differentcontainer").html(imgname);
});
```

So I'd want to get the value of the comoplete img-tag and use it after a click on a different element. As I already use jquery this would possibly make most sense sticking to it .

Thanks!

Comment: $(this).next('img').attr('src')

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [jQuery Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_syntax.asp)

> The `jQuery syntax` is tailor-made for selecting `HTML` elements and
>   performing some action on the element(s). Basic syntax is:
>
> > $(selector).action();
>
> A **`$`** sign to define/access jQuery.
>
> A **`(selector)`** to "query (or find)" HTML elements.
>
> A jQuery **`action()`** to be performed on the element(s)

```js
$(".productbox").click(function() {
  var imgname = $(this).html();
  $(".differentcontainer").html(imgname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productbox"><img style="width:50px; height:50px" src="https://i2.wp.com/mightywidow.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/12/11519100485_ddfd5be329_z.jpg?fit=640%2C361&amp;ssl=1" title="1"></div>
<div class="productbox"><img style="width:50px; height:50px" src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcSnXSQpzvR2frx8nzq-rxxQZsOjPtRWNVVRwoU7-NsUAtGYUOom" title="2"></div>
<div class="productbox"><img style="width:50px; height:50px" src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/e6/63/d0/e663d0bf3d57da87ef9992cddd5af05c--kindness-ideas-acts-of-kindness.jpg" title="3"></div>

<div class="differentcontainer">
  <!-- the value of the image shall be put in here as <img src="..."> -->
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! So var imgname = $(this).html(); does use all the content of the clicked parent-element but not the parent element itself? SO in terms of a more complicated markup-structure I'd need to specify the "this" better?

Comment: `$(this)` says that the click which is performed on `.productbox`. So all the content inside the clicked element will be taken

Answer (score 0):

Juts get the html in the div, something like this:

```js
$(".productbox").click(function() {
    var imgname = $(this).html();
   $(".differentcontainer").empty();
     $(".differentcontainer").html(imgname);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="productbox"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150"></div>
<div class="productbox"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/140x100"></div>
<div class="productbox"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/200x100"></div>

<div class="differentcontainer">
<!-- the value of the image shall be put in here as <img src="..."> -->
</div>
```

Comment: No need for `$(".differentcontainer").empty();`